# Tool to generate Splash Screen & Wallpaper for all Sizes & Devices using Single Click

Tags: android

Like we use **Android Asset Studio** to *Generate Launcher Icon* for all *devices and dimensions*, in a same way i want to ***Generate Splash Screen*** for all *devices and dimensions*

can we have any **Tool to create Splash Screen for all devices** using single click in a easy way *(by just uploading Image to Tool* like we do in **AAS** *[Android Asset Studio]*) ?

As I think developers can use that **Tool**, even to ***Generate Wallpapers*** for *different - different* **sizes and devices**, it *will reduce the time of resizing the images* as well.

See below Screen, like we use ***AAS*** to *Generate Launcher Icon* for all **Devices**:

[image]

**Note:** I also tried this link http://tools.android.com/recent/assetstudiointegration,
but it also *helpful to generate* ***Launcher Icons, Menu Icons, Action Bar Icons, Tab Icons & Notification Icons....*** not to **generate** *Splash Screen*.

Comment: There are probably just too many different sizes, densities, and aspect ratios of device screens out there.